# How see the dependence between two variables that gives opposite values? Dataframe analysis

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I am trying to analyze this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/wjkwok/spotify-song-features-analysis/data) and I did some analysis but now I found an interesting question that I want to answer but I am struggling on how do it.

Every record of the dataframe is a song, described by some columns. The target is the column "liked" that tells if the user likes or not likes the song.
Here a screen of the first 10 rows:

[image]

I also divided the dataframe in "liked" and "not liked" songs and then I plotted using some histograms the data of some columns.
Here the two histograms where I plotted the data for "Speechiness" and "Danceability".

[image]
[image]

From the first histogram is clear that the almost all "not liked" songs have a low Speechiness value. But also some "liked" songs have low Speechiness values.

From the second hist we can clearly see that almost all "liked" songs have a Danceability values greater than 0.5. But also some "not liked" songs have higher Danceability values.

So based on that I am curious to know why some songs are "not liked" even if they have a high danceability value? and why some songs are "liked" even if they have a low Speechiness?

I really don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Looks like an opportunity to run a logistic regression and look at the coefficient outputs to determine the impact of the individual variables on the target.

Answer (score 0):

Some songs are "not liked" even if they have a high danceability value because there are those of us who enjoy symphonies, concertos, organ works, fugues, etc. You can't dance to those neither is there any singing or *speechinees* but we simply enjoy listening to them.
This is the same reason why some songs are "liked" even if they have a low Speechiness.

Clearly, any of the tree-based models would solve this problem for you. Speechiness and Dancability aren't the only variables there. There is loudness, instrumentalness, tempo, etc.

Comment: Exactly, my thought what is the correlation with likeability and other attributes in your table?